# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Variable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-10

After I upgraded to Tensorflow 1.0.1, many errors appeared, and it soon become a mess. Currently the tf.Variable function isn't working. But the thing more strange is that if I use it in Python Interpreter, it's fine. I've tried reinstall&reboot for several times, but it doesn't fix the problem. How can I fix it to get my learning machine back to work?
PC: HP 280 G2 SFF
OS: Windows 10 Home
Tensorflow version: Tensorflow 1.0.1 downgraded to 1.0.0
Python: Python 3.5.3

Comment: Is your file named 'tensorflow.py'?

Comment: No, it's name is 8.py.

Comment: Could you be trying to import tensorflow from within the tensorflow github clone? This is not expected to work.

Comment: Yes, I did that, still troubleshooting.

Comment: Use pip to install Tensorflow follow the official [site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) to install it. Make sure you don't have code.py and tensorflow.py as local file names. Thanks!